# iPhone: fb://... URL opening the Premier Inn app, not Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, url

I don't know a lot about how the iOS handles URLs, but it appears to be doing something strange on my phone...

We have a 'Like' button in our app, that when clicked on is supposed to open the Facebook application (or Safari, if Facebook is not installed).  For some reason, when I click it on my phone, it opens the "Premier Inn" app.  I have both the Facebook App and Premier Inn app installed on my phone, but not sure why Facebook isn't opening when the following code is executed:

```
NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/BIG_NUMBER_HERE"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: fanPageURL]) { ... }
```

For obvious reasons, I've substituted the page number for BIG_NUMBER_HERE in the above code.

Can anyone explain why this might be going wrong?  Could the Premier Inn app have "registered" itself as a handler of the fb:// urls somehow?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you suggest, it sounds like Premier Inn has registered as a handler for "fb". There's no central registry to stop applications from using the same URL scheme, it's really just down to good luck and reasonable namespace choices by developers.

Edit: I can't find a canonical source for this, but the handler application that's called is that which is most recently installed.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be the case.  I uninstalled the "Premier Inn" app, and then the URLs opened in Safari.  After this, I uninstalled and then reinstalled the Facebook app, and finally they opened in Facebook application, as expected.  So I guess the Premier Inn had just registered itself as the handler for "fb://" links - a bit cheeky, if you ask me!

Answer (score 0):

try change that `page` to `profile`.